# How to call ondraw method from the mainactivity

Tags: android

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

Paint p;
com.example.lean.myapplication.keypaint keypain;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.list_fragment);
    Canvas canvas = null;
    keypain = new com.example.lean.myapplication.keypaint(this);
    keypain.ondraw(canvas);

}
```

I cannot call the ondraw function in keypaint sucessfully. i am very new to programming skill. hope someone can help me. thank you very much

```
public class keypaint extends View {
Paint p;

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    p=new Paint();
    Bitmap b= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
    p.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, p);
}




public keypaint(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
```

}

Comment: the system calls onDraw.

Comment: ... and view.invalidate() should force system to call it ... but your code has no sens ... you will get NPE ... also onDraw is protected not public

Comment: i don't even get it. could you mind providing the code